# What is best practice design for internal traffic between microservices?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, bandwidth, amazon-route53, architecture

I have two PHP written microservices A & B. Endpoints are a.example.com and b.example.com. Both services need to be public accessible. In addition, service B makes a lot of curl requests to a.example.com while processing.

Both services are running on same AWS VPC (within same private network). I also have an external CDN (eg, Akamai) for each endpoints.

Design 1:

```
Public and Service B make requests to A
                 |
                 V
           a.example.com
                 |
                 V
                CDN
                 |
                 V
        Public Load Balancer
                 |
                 V
      Web Servers for service A
```

- Higher cost because more bandwidth cost from AWS
- More protection on service A as it is behind CDN
- Slower service B response time as traffic goes out to Cloud and comes back in

Design 2:

```
     Public makes requests to A        Service B makes requests to A
                 |                                  |
                 V                                  V
           a.example.com                 a-internal.example.com
                 |                                  |
                 V                                  |
                CDN                                 |
                 |                                  |
                 V                                  V
        Public Load Balancer              Internal Load Balancer
                 |                                  |
                 V                                  V
              Web     servers       for      service   A
```

- Faster service B response time as traffic is within private network
- Lower bandwidth cost as traffic is within private network
- A risk of service A may be smashed by service B
- Extra cost for the additional internal load balancer
- Complexity of maintaining two a. and a-internal. endpoints

**Question**, Are these correct designs for microservices inter-connections? If not, what's the common design for microservices inter-connections?

**Bonus question**, is split DNS (eg, AWS Route 53 private zone) a good use case if I want to maintain the single endpoint a.example.com instead of two (a. & a-internal.).

Comment: You missed the obvious 3rd option, where you don't maintain two loadbalancers but allow Service B to bypass the CDN and send those requests directly to the public loadbalancer for Service A. - BTW If you're worried about one of your own applications causing a denial of service on your other you probably need to improve your design.

Comment: Indeed that is the 3rd option, the least attractive one I think. It is not taking advantage of the private network speed, while still costs the bandwidth charge from AWS.

Comment: Please edit your question to make the problem / question clear. Are you asking for design advice? I think option 3 does go over the private network, but it does charge for data. Service B hitting the server for Service A is cheapest, but then you might have to hard-code IPs, and if you auto scale the servers could change. Option 3 may be best.